# Active Record Performance Issues

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails application and I'm currently running into performance issues at scale. I am using Rails 4 and MySQL for my backend.

I have a model named Coaches and I would like to group my response so that it only sends coaches with distinct emails.

Here is an example:

`Coach.group(:email)`

However when i use this code with my production workload, it takes far too long to for Active Record to produce the result, see below.

```
Coach Load (193743.7ms)  SELECT `coaches`.* FROM `coaches` WHERE `coaches`.`deleted_at` IS NULL GROUP BY `coaches`.`email`
```

I have an index on the email and deleted_at column in my coaches table.

Has anyone run into similar issues in the past?

Comment: Can you tell me how much records are there in `coaches` table ? 
Secondly do you need all of the column's in response from `coaches` table ? 
Rails ORM takes lot of time so if there are lot of column's then you need to select only those which you actually need

Comment: I have around 600,000 records in the coaches table. And I am using this query as the base to the ajax-datatables-rails gem, which provides pagination, sorting, and searching later (github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails). So I do need all of the records in this query

Comment: My guess is there are too many unique emails. Do you really need to use group here? maybe distinct is what you need.

Comment: @leiliu how else would i return all coaches that have a unique email?

Comment: By your approach, assume there is a coach with two different emails, you will get two grouped records; Assume these are two different coaches with the same email, you will have no ideal which one your group will return. Am i right?

Comment: @leiliu you're correct on both accounts. But for my case, if two coaches have the same email, I don't care which one is returned, just that only that the email turns up exactly once

Answer (score 0):

You need to also apply `indexing` on `deleted_at` column and also one proper solution is that use pagination like use data in limit format that will help you in these case.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have an index on my deleted_at column (so i updated the question). And i like the idea of using pagination, however this is used inside the get_raw_records method of the ajax-datatable-rails gem, which handles pagination later in the process (https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails)